# set_post_thumbnail() shows Unattached on backend under Media

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails

I'm using front-end form to submit content and use

```
// Set thumbnail
$newupload = set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $att_id );
echo $newupload;
```

to set the Featured image on the post. It actually works fine but it does not show up in the backend under Media page.

[image]

Should I just ignore it as long as everything works good? or find a way to fix this so it shows the title of post has this image as featured image?

Comment: Is "front-end form" a plugin? Please post more code. What you have posted is out of context and not sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're uploading files via your own form, a file is attached by setting `post_parent` of the attachment to the ID of the post you want it attached to. Setting a post thumbnail doesn't attach the file to that post.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now I understand how this works. `media_handle_upload('file' , $post_id );` sets `post_parent` to `$post_id` correct? Now my issue is I set $post_id to `0` and get `$attachment_id` which I use `set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attachment_id );` to set featured image. Is it possible to update `$post_id` to new ID when I execute  `set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attachment_id );` ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how your code works. You can use `wp_update_post` to change `post_parent`, but I don't know why you can't know the correct post ID before you save the attachment.

Comment: Because I'm using AJAX to upload attachment file first before I submit the entire form. that way I can get the `$attachment_id` that I can use to `$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);` then `set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $att_id );`. I didn't want to upload entire code to make it look messy.

Comment: So I used `wp_update_post(
                    array(
                        'ID' => $att_id, 
                        'post_parent' => $post_id
                    )
                );` update `post_parent` to my problem! thank you so much for the help!